# Не срабатывает событие keydown при нажатии трех клавиш

Tags: javascript, pixijs

Не вызывается событие `keydown` при одновременном нажатии верхней, правой, левой стрелок. Оно также не вызывается для левой стрелки, если нажать одновременно верхнюю и правые стрелки, а потом уже еще нажать левую. Однако, все работает для нижней, левой, правой стрелок. Почему не работает только для сочетаний с верхней стрелкой?

```
        var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600, {backgroundColor: 0x1099bb});

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);


        var stage = new PIXI.Container();


        var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('http://pixijs.github.io/examples/_assets/basics/bunny.png');


        var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);


        bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
        bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;


        bunny.position.x = 200;
        bunny.position.y = 150;

        stage.addChild(bunny);

        var KEY_CODE = {
            LEFT: 37,
            UP: 38,
            RIGHT: 39,
            DOWN: 40
        };
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handlerDown, true);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', handlerUp, true);

        var keys = [];
        function handlerUp(e) {
            keys.splice(keys.indexOf(e.which), 1);
        }
        function handlerDown(e) {
            if (keys.indexOf(e.which) < 0)
                keys.push(e.which);
        }

        animate();
        function animate() {
            var vx = 0;
            var vy = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i <= keys.length; i++) {
                switch (keys[i]) {
                    case KEY_CODE.UP:
                        vy -= 2;
                        break;
                    case KEY_CODE.DOWN:
                        vy += 2;
                        break;
                    case KEY_CODE.RIGHT:
                        vx += 2;
                        break
                    case KEY_CODE.LEFT:
                        vx -= 2;
                        break;
                }
            }
            bunny.position.x += vx;
            bunny.position.y += vy;
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(stage);
        }
```

Comment: Код не читал пока, но а в других приложениях типа текстового редактора работает? Ибо это вполне могут оказаться аппаратные ограничения клавиатуры.

Comment: Поддерживаю @andreymal. Уверен на 80%, что дело в клавиатуре.

Comment: @andreymal действительно, проблема в аппаратном ограничении клавиатуры. Проверил, с помощью утилиты для проверки клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в аппаратном ограничении клавиатуры.

Comment: @kff а вот и является) Правда, вопрос всё равно надо закрывать